# sql multi condition within one table

Tags: mysql, join

got table like this

```
+---------+------------+----------+
| user_id | project_id | group_id |
+---------+------------+----------+
|       1 |          1 |        1 |
|       1 |         10 |        1 |
|       2 |          2 |        1 |
|       2 |          3 |        1 |
|       3 |          3 |        2 |
+---------+------------+----------+
```

looking for just those user_id from group_id=1 but not being present in project_id=2. in this case desired output would be

```
+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
```

my problem with

```
SELECT user_id
FROM STATUS
WHERE group_id = 1 and user_id NOT IN (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM STATUS
    WHERE project_id = 2
    GROUP BY user_id)
GROUP BY user_id
```

is that the subquery has ~1 000 000 rows and this makes whole query very slow (>5 sec. in reality).
would it be any clever join for this, or go rather for 2 selects? thank you for your tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another alternative for `MINUS` in mysql in using `joins`,  use a join like below:

```
select s1.user_id from (SELECT user_id,project_id,group_id
FROM STATUS 
WHERE group_id = 1) s1
join 
(SELECT user_id,project_id,group_id
FROM STATUS 
WHERE project_id = 2) s2 on s1.user_id <> s2.user_id
```